# How to let GraphQL know if I want to resolve a field from another rootQuery?

Tags: javascript, graphql

Let me explain:

```js
type SecondType {
  id: String
}

type FirstType {
  id: String
  secondTypes: [SecondType]
}

type Query {
  firstTypes: [FirstType]
  secondTypes: [SecondType]
}
//
const resolver = {
  Query: {
    firstTypes: fetchFirstTypes,
    secondTypes: fetchSecondTypes
  }
};
```

The idea is that if there's a parent-child relationship between `firstType` and `secondType`, for example `secondType` contains it's parent (`firstType`) id, through the result of the previous resolver, `secondTypes` inside query `firstTypes` can fetch `secondTypes` related to it's parent `firstType`. What I've experienced is that the resolver of `firstType` is looking for a key named `secondTypes` from the result of `fetchFirstTypes`. But I want to let GraphQL know that it needs to resolve `secondTypes` from the resolver of `Query.secondTypes`. How can I do that? Maybe is there a way to write "fallback reducers" of a field? So if it doesn't find a key from the result, it can look for a resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of your question, you need a resolver for the key secondTypes which is present in FirstType. For this,
you can make the resolver as follows:

```
const resolver = {
  Query: {
    firstTypes: fetchFirstTypes,
    secondTypes: fetchSecondTypes
  },
  FirstType: {
      secondTypes: (parent, args, context, info) => {
          // Here you will get the parent id(FirstType) parent.id
          // From Here resolve the secondtypes data
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: I get the idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. So FirstType doesn't have a field secondTypes initially from the value returned by resolver - fetchFirstTypes, I want to add secondTypes manually. Is that still possible?

Comment: Normally the above solution should work. Adding SecondTypes manually in the fetchFirstTypes also work . you should return the object that matches the fields present in the type mentioned

Comment: Currently I'm using express-graphql, where I can't define my resolvers of the root queries inside `Query`, also the resolver functions parameters are different too. In the above example I only can define my root queries at the first level of the reducer object, if I pass them inside `Query`, it throws cannot return null for non nullable field. As I've spent all my day trying out different things since I've asked this question, there can't be any reasons why it doesn't work for me other than the package I use. - even if it would be surprising if this popular package wouldn't be able to do that

Comment: This might help: https://softchris.github.io/pages/graphql-express.html#adding-express-graphql